# How can I use string_split in Update Query?

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE [PATS].[ReportSubscription]
   SET [ScheduleID] = @ScheduleID
  ,[ReferenceID] = @ReferenceID
  ,[ReferenceType] = @ReferenceType
  ,[Schedule] = @Schedule
  ,[Day] = @Day
  ,[Time] = @Time
  ,[ProjectID] = @ProjectID
  ,[LastSentDate] = @LastSentDate
  ,[UserID] = @UserID
  ,[CreatedBy] = @CreatedBy
  ,[CreatedDate] = @CreatedDate
  ,[UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy
  ,[UpdatedDate] = @UpdatedDate
  WHERE ID=@ID AND Day IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Day,','))
```

This solution is not working. I tried to run my query but is not working.

Comment: "not working" doesn't help.  What is the problem?  A syntax error?  The wrong data gets updated?  What does the data look like?

Comment: Means when I run my query value doesn't split.

Comment: Please provide examples of the data you are using for @Day.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you'd want to update the table and set Day = `@Day` if you are later trying to string_split `@Day` in the where clause.